# $route.reload loading the page from server in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get my hands around angular. I am trying to reload my page using $route.reload. I dont want it to go to the server when I try to reload. Is there a way to reload the page in angular without going to the server, reloading the information the page got from the last server call.

I am calling this function for the reload.

```
     $scope.reload = function () {
            $route.reload();
        };
```

Any help/ideas would be appreciated